# Whom does he play game to get?

Tags: questions, gerunds

I play a video game that I save someone, and someone asks whom do I save.

Does it make sense of 'whom does you play game to save?' or 'to save whom does you play game?'

Comment: None of those sentences make sense. You can revise the question. Put more details and referecnes.

Comment: @Maulik V♦ I revised it.

Comment: @gogosing Please would you give us the context for the sentence you want to write.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I revised it.

Comment: By 'play game', do you mean you are only pretending to save someone?

Comment: @Kate Bunting No video game.

Comment: "No, I am talking about playing a video game." In that case, someone might ask you "Who are you saving, in the game?" or "Who are you trying to save?" (Yes, _whom_ is strictly correct, but in informal speech almost everyone would use _who_.)

Comment: [correction: I play a game where I save someone. **a game**]

Answer (score 1):

The OP writes

> I play game that I save someone, and someone asks whom do I save.

The Present Continuous tense is used if the game is being played while the speaker is watching.

1. **Who** are you saving? (most common)

The speaker could make a slightly longer question:

2. **Who** are you trying to save in the game?

Use the interrogative pronoun "who". If this were an English exam then I *might* suggest using the formal equivalent–whom–but because the context is informal, it would be inappropriate to use "whom".
3. **Whom** are you saving? (too formal)

If the act of saving occurred in the past and is completed, the question would be

- Who **did** you save?
  Who **did** you try to save?
  Whom **did** you save?

Answer (score 0):

The whole sentence needs re-writing I think to clarify what is going on. I suggest:

> In the video game which I am playing, I saved someone and I was asked who I had saved.

The main changes are (1) I clarified it is a video game, (2) I put save into the past as it must have happened before they asked you, (3) I made the last part passive to avoid repeating *someone* which would be confusing as they would be referring to two different people.

I am sure there are many other ways of re-writing the sentence.